# stuck with this error "simplejson.errors.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)"

Tags: python, json, web-scraping

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
import re
import json
import requests
def Table():
                table = pd.read_json("https://www.nmc.org.in/MCIRest/open/getPaginatedData?service=getPaginatedDoctor&draw=1&columns%5B0%5D%5Bdata%5D=0&columns%5B0%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B0%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B1%5D%5Bdata%5D=1&columns%5B1%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B1%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B2%5D%5Bdata%5D=2&columns%5B2%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B2%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B3%5D%5Bdata%5D=3&columns%5B3%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B3%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B4%5D%5Bdata%5D=4&columns%5B4%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B4%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B5%5D%5Bdata%5D=5&columns%5B5%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B5%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B5%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B5%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B5%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B6%5D%5Bdata%5D=6&columns%5B6%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B6%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B6%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B6%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bvalue%5D=&columns%5B6%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&order%5B0%5D%5Bcolumn%5D=0&order%5B0%5D%5Bdir%5D=asc&start=20000&length=8751&search%5Bvalue%5D=&search%5Bregex%5D=false&name=&registrationNo=&smcId=&year=2020&_=1611587198138")['data']
                with open('C:\\Users\\SmartDB\\Desktop\\2020_out_2.csv', 'w', newline="") as f:
                    writer = csv.writer(f)
                    writer.writerow(
                  ['Year Of The Info', 'Registration#', 'State Medical Councils', 'Name', 'FatherName'])
                    data = []
                    for item in table:
                        writer.writerow(item[1:6])
                        required = item[6]
                        match = re.search(
                        r"openDoctorDetailsnew\('([^']*)', '([^']*)'", required)
                    data.append(match.group().split("'")[1:4:2])
                    print("Data Saved Into out.csv")
                return data

def Details():
            names = []
            items = []
            for doc, val in Table():
                print(f"Extracting DoctorID# {doc}, RegValue# {val}")
                json = {'doctorId': doc, 'regdNoValue': val}
                r = requests.post("https://www.nmc.org.in/MCIRest/open/getDataFromService? 
service=getDoctorDetailsByIdImr",json=json).json()
                try:
                    if r.keys() not in names:
                          names.append(r.keys())
                    items.append(r.values())
                except:
                     pass 

            print("Done")
            return names, items


def Save():
            with open('C:\\Users\\SmartDB\\Desktop\\2020_data_2.csv','w', newline="") as d:
                writer = csv.writer(d)
                n, i = Details()
                writer.writerows(n)
                writer.writerows(i)
            
Save()
```

while doing web scraping during extraction i get this error"simplejson.errors.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)" so please help me to solve this error and data comes in out.csv file but not in data.csv file.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

As it was pointed out, pandas.read_json() takes a URL too. I ran your code and it ran successfully all the way.

The problem may be that you are getting a non-200 response from your endpoint and the response body is not JSON.

This could be because you have a typo (likely) or your authorisation isn't valid (unlikely because I just ran it and it worked) or maybe you made too many requests and the API server blocked your IP temporarily :)

Could be a host of other reasons too. Maybe you can post the result of your request before you convert to JSON and we can help better i.e.

```
r = requests.post("https://www.nmc.org.in/MCIRest/open/getDataFromService?service=getDoctorDetailsByIdImr", json=json)
        j = r.json()
```

and show us what `r` is.

Make sure all parts of your request are correctly typed in.

---

Your first line seems to be trying to use pandas to read a json file except you have just passed a URL string.

```
table = pd.read_json("https://www.nmc.org.in/MCIRest/open/getPaginatedData?service=getPaginatedDoctor&draw=1&columns%5B0%...")['data']
```

This is not a JSON. You have to actually download the JSON from the web-page using a GET request and then try to read it as JSON.

The error means that pd.read_json() tried to read some URL string as a JSON, and of course, it is not one.

Comment: According to https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html passing a URL to `read_json` is valid and pandas will download it for you

Comment: what exact change i have to do in my code

Comment: @freundTech you're right. In fact, I ran the code with the URL and it ran successfully all the way.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that the URL you are requesting with `pd.read_json()` is wrong, as that is the only place in your code that reads json.

`simplejson.errors.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)` means that it failed to decode json, at line 1, column 1 of the json test (Not line 1 column 1 of your sourcecode).

Most likely the URL is wrong and returned an empty respone instead of json.